# Completely change IDE language in Netbeans 6.8

Tags: netbeans, netbeans6.8

I installed the lastest version from NetBeans IDE (6.8). I tried to install it in English, but it forces me to install it in Portuguese (OS Language). I've googled about it and I found that I should add `--locale en:US` when launching the program.

It almost works perfectly: some things are still in portuguese. For example, the descriptions from the Tasks tab and the Services tab's name.

Is it possible to change it, without having to change my OS' language?

Thank you.

Comment: The setting is determined by your OS language.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Netbeans automatically uses the Windows system default language as the default user interface language. I believe that it means to be a nice feature for localization. But I personally find it uncomfortable because I have been used with English interface.

After I did some Google search, I learned a few tips to set the Netbeans UI language.
1. Temporary Solution

Add `"--locale en:US"` at the end of Netbeans startup command.

```
"C:\Program Files\NetBeans6.8\bin\netbeans.exe"  --locale en:US
```

2. Permanent Solution
Go to Netbeans installation directory, for example,

```
C:\Program Files\NetBeans6.8\etc
```

Open `"netbeans.conf"` and find netbeans default option line

```
netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-XX:PermSize=32m -J-XX:MaxPermSize=200m -J-Xverify:none -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true"
```

Add `"-J-Duser.language=en -J-Duser.region=US"` to the end of this line

```
netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-XX:PermSize=32m -J-XX:MaxPermSize=200m -J-Xverify:none -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Duser.language=en -J-Duser.region=US"
```

It would be nice that there is an option to allow me choose the user interface language in the next Netbeans release.

Comment: +1 Using Netbeans 8 and this still works.. and netbeans still doesn't have the option to choose the language in the UI.