# Set Netbeans Console to English

Tags: java, netbeans, locale

Somehow Netbeans prints German warnings to the console when building a project. Likely because my laptop is set to German, but why it is exactly I am not sure. The terminal is in English, the Java JVM locale is set to English and the netbeans.conf is also set to English.

- JVM Local > java -Duser.language=en -Duser.region=US
- netbeans.conf > netbeans_default_options="... -J-Duser.language=en -J-Duser.region=US"

But still I get the following console warnings in German, which is annoying when Googling the meaning of these warnings:

```
Systemmodulpfad nicht zusammen mit -source 11 festgelegt
io/ost/finance/io/TransactionWriterForDone.java:[43,58] Nicht-varargs-Aufruf von varargs-Methode mit ungenauem Argumenttyp für den letzten Parameter.
  Führen Sie für einen varargs-Aufruf eine Umwandlung mit Cast in java.lang.Object aus
  Führen Sie für einen Nicht-varargs-Aufruf eine Umwandlung mit Cast in java.lang.Object[] aus, um diese Warnung zu unterdrücken
```

Anybody has an answer? Is there some way that the Java compiler is still set to German?

Comment: For a locale that should be `-Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US` Whether that will make the difference, I don't know

Comment: If I remove the -J,Netbeans won't start, so that doesn't work

Comment: According to this post, the -J prepended is actually correct https://stackoverflow.com/a/1955245/4721273

Comment: *...so that doesn't work...* I'm talking about the *general* system property involved. Whether extra prompting is required for *Netbeans*, I don't know

Comment: I changed the complete system language to German, that did the trick... but that was not the answer I was looking for :/